# NameError in Posts#index (undefined local variable or method `post' for undefined local variable or method `post' for #<#<Class:0xce96b50>:0xc568590>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting this error in my rails app =>

**undefined local variable or method `post' for #<#:0xc568590>**

i'm using ruby 2.3 & rails 5.2,
 here is the code
**Index.html.haml**

```
- @posts.each do |post|
  =link_to (image_tag post.image.url(:small))
  %h2= link_to post.title, post
%p
  = post.comments.count
  Comments

= link_to "Add New Inspiration", new_post_path
```

the error is raising at  **= post.comments.count**

and here is my **post controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

    def index
        @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def show
        @comments = Comment.where(post_id: @post)
    end
    def new
        @post = current_user.posts.build
    end
    def create
        @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

        if @post.save
            redirect_to @post
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
    def edit

    end
    def update
        if @post.update(post_params)
            redirect_to @post
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end
    def destroy
        @post.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    private

    def find_post
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :link, :description,:image)
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you add the whole stack trace of the error you're getting?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @SebastianPalma thanks for your help. It was the indentation as Amit Patel said.

Answer (score 0):

It's indentation issue. Try below

```
- @posts.each do |post|
  =link_to (image_tag post.image.url(:small))
  %h2= link_to post.title, post
  %p
    = post.comments.count
    Comments

  = link_to "Add New Inspiration", new_post_path
```

Comment: You are right @Amit Patel. Its the indentation. Thanks very much

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error..._